# check if row is in table in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have to write a script that updates some mysql tables. For this purpose I am provided with a .dbf file that contains the up-to-date data. So what I am doing is:

1. Convert .dbf file to .sql file (using [this script by xtranophilist](https://github.com/xtranophilist/dbf2sql/blob/master/dbf2sql.php) )
2. Extract mysql statements from .sql file and execute them (Creating mysql table "`temp`" and filling it with data)
3. Get data from freshly created table ("`temp`") where column `tablenr` = '1' and check for each row if row exists in other table ("`data_side1`")

1.and 2. is working so far, now I am wondering how to do 3:

**How do you check if some row exists in some table in MySQL via PHP? And what is the best way to do so?**

Comment: There are joins for that.

Comment: A `WHERE` clause with an `EXISTS`? Do you understand how to write SQL statements or are you asking for SO to write the code for you?

Comment: @AgRizzo: Since I am new to mysql i did not know how to get this working. Virus721 gave me the keyword, that seems to be what i was searching for. I apologize if I gave the impression of looking for someone to do the work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

> SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM data_side1 WHERE ...)

For more details please check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html